# Schema for notification system for users

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, schema

I'm writing an web application for users who need to be able to receive notices from administrators when they login. These notices should be displayed on their dashboard.

Once a user has read a message, they can dismiss it. New users should obviously not be shown messages before they were created.

I'm having two problems with designing the schema:

1. How do I identify that a user has "dismissed" a message?
2. How do new users only see messages after they've been created?

Here's the table for notifications:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Notification] 
(
  [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [Message] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
  [DateCreated] [datetime] NOT NULL,
  [CreatedById] [int] NOT NULL
)
```

For #1, I was thinking of creating a table (`DismissedNotification_User`) that would map between a `Notification.Id` and a `User.Id`. If a pair exists, then the user dismissed that notification. However, I'm not sure if this is the best approach (`not in` vs a `left join`)?

For #2, the easiest approach that I see is by adding a `DateCreated` column to users and when adding a condition onto #1 (`where [DateCreated] >= [User].DateCreated`).

I don't want cookies involved because that really adds unnecessary weight to the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that your own solutions for #1 and #2 here seem fine.

The link table to represent a 'dismissed' notification makes sense otherwise you end up having to create one row per user up front, to represent a notification as opposed to one notification record.

I think also for #2, having a created date for the notification and user would be a sensible option too. The other suggestions to use a 'dismissed' column would not enable you to only display notification AFTER a user was created if you're reliant on the option of a linked table as you would end up with all notifications, not just those since the user existed.

Comment: Thanks - I'm going to stick with my original plan.

Comment: I think that's the most sensible option, I did something similar with an alerts system lately. I contemplated inserting a row per user and removing them, but since we have 2-3k users and the alerts are probably only relevant to 10-20 users at a time, it seemed inefficient to add thousands of rows which would never be touched.

Answer (score 0):

- **For #1:** Add a new column to the `Notification` table something like `dismissed` or `readed` of data type `bit` i.e `boolean` with a default value 0 or false, then in your application once the user open the message, update the value of `dismissed` to `1`, I saw other systems that add a button called Mark as readed so that ensure that the user read it.
- **For #2:** You can use this field `dismissed` to show only those messages that hasn't been dismissed yet to the users as they hasn't been opended and readed by the user.

So the notifications table would look something like:

```
[Notification] 
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Message] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [DateCreated] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedById] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Readed] bit Default(0)
)
```

You will need an extra table to store the notifications for each user like,

```
dbo.UserNotifications
(
    UserId, NotificationId
)
```

In your application when a user logon to the system check for the notifications with `readed = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

You might join this two tasks by creating a table containing both a user and a message. When administrator sends a message you create entry for each existing (active?) user. If you do not need history you can delete message after user dismissed a notification; otherwise you should add 'Dismissed' column. This way you do not need complicated queries to get notifications you need to present to user.